# Removing index.php - official guide not working (code igniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to remove the index.php in the url for Code Igniter. According to the official guide, I should add the following code to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is not working.

So I do more searches and some say that I should remove the default configuration on the index page, so I make the changes in the config.php file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

It is still not working. Then, on more searches, I found different version of the code, like this one (there is just an example, I have tried many version already)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I initially put the code in the .htaccess of the root directory, but as it is not working, I also try adding it to .htaccess in other directory. Yet, still not working.

I am just using the default welcome page for testing, so I am sure it is not the problem of coding. i.e.

```
http://localhost/projectFolder/CodeIgniter/welcome/
```

Anybody got idea what have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that whatever folder that `http://localhost/projectFolder/CodeIgniter/` maps to is your docroot and that the `.htaccess` file is inside that directory.

If that is the case, then your code is correct - so it's a matter of your apache config. Make sure that you are allowing `.htaccess` files by changing the Directory block - `AllowOverride All`.

[Take a look at this page for help doing that.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles)

Comment: This seems to be on the right path, but as I am using Mac and XAMPP, it seems that the link is not applicable to me. Do you have a version for Mac? (I am googling, but seems not much help out there)

Comment: Here's a link to the "what's where" on xampp for mac: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#876  --  You need to edit the `/Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf` file. If you're running vhosts, then you would edit a file named `vhosts.conf` (should be either in or around the same directory - maybe in a `sites-available` directory).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should work for you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|public|themes|captcha|robots|documents|\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectFolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes to config file

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then in ur .htaccess try

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure that you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in your apache configuration

The .htaccess file should be in root directory of your project, ie outside application folder

Comment: I am already using the configuration you posted and I have tried changing the script to the one you provided but it is still not working. I guess it is the mod_rewrite thing. How do I enable it? (I am using Mac with XAMPP.)