# In codeigniter redirecting is not working without index.php?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter while redirecting a page index.php is not loading by default,So i have tried the below code in htaccess file. I have installed php 5.3.10, apache server and postgres database. so if any new configuration have to be done apart from changing .htaccess and httpd.conf then please let me know. I have seen previous questions asked on the same issue and i referred everything from those questions but still I am not able to solve this. please let me know what extra things to be done.

**.htaccess file**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the #request to index.php RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond $1 !^/(index\.php|assets/|humans\.txt) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**httpd.conf file**
    ServerName localhost

```
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188957/removing-index-php-offical-guide-not-working-code-igniter?rq=1

Comment: Is rewrite module enabled?

Comment: make sure that `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: check file permission sudo chmod 777 -R projectDirectory/

Comment: @Pooshonk Sir,i have refereed that link already i tried those code,still it is not working.

Comment: @RossWilson Sir,I changed the config file and i sent $config['index_page'] = '' also;Still it is not working

Comment: She is done with .htaccess code also she done with chmod and httpd.conf edit, so guys please read the problem first then answer.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your question. Are you wanting to remove index.php from the routing e.g. `domain.com/index.php/site/page` becomes `domain.com/site/page`

Comment: @RossWilson Yes i want remove index.php in url

Comment: In that case can you show what url you've tried and what you have in your routes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following things you should do for avoiding index.php in url

- Always make sure you have .htaccess file. which you have already.
- Include contents in .htaccess which @charlie has suggested above.
- Edit httpd.conf file using nano command and include main thing keep allowoveride All
- First disable rewrite mode and enable it again then restart apache2 server using following commands.

  **sudo a2dismod rewrite //which disables the rewrite mode**

  **sudo a2enmod rewrite //which enables the rewrite mode**

  **sudo service apache2 restart //which restarts your apache**

Thats all you need to do. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Charle Sir, I have tried this code it's not working